# Why was this question about VtM dice mechanics deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I just happened to randomly click on the "deleted recent answers" link in my profile, and noticed that [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68950/how-to-calculate-the-probability-of-the-outcome-of-a-vampire-the-masqurade-roll/68957#68957) had been deleted along with its question, [How to calculate the probability of the outcome of a Vampire the Masqurade roll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68950/how-to-calculate-the-probability-of-the-outcome-of-a-vampire-the-masqurade-roll) (both links 10k+ only).

Since I don't have 10k rep on this site, I can't see when, *why* or by whom the question was deleted.  Sure, it may not have been the greatest question ever, but it didn't seem *that* terrible to me.  And my answer was at +5 score, so I'm pretty sure [it couldn't have been deleted by the question author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222).

I'm not terribly concerned about losing the answer itself.  Sure, I did spend some time on it, but in the end the content was just a trivial AnyDice script and some explanation of basic probability theory.  It's not the greatest answer I've ever written, nor even the greatest answer that could've been written for that question.  But the deletion of the question itself puzzled me enough that I figured it was worth asking about.

All that said, this is mainly just idle curiosity.  If the answer turns out to be that "there were reasons, but they're kind of private and we'd rather not discuss them in public here" or anything like that, I'll be fine with that, too.

Comment: Regarding info you can’t see below 10k: It looks like the author wanted to delete it (and couldn’t due to existing answers, so @SevenSidedDie was the one to actually do it), but the comments regarding *why* seem to have been purged.

Comment: @KRyan There was one initial comment about cross-posting that didn't mention deletion, since it was before they wanted it deleted; all communication about possibly deleting it only existed in flags. I should have added a comment explaining the deletion at the time though; I'll correct that oversight now, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question was deleted at the request of the original poster.  In large part because it was cross posted on another stack.

You can find the stat.se version of the question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174099/how-to-calculate-the-probability-of-the-outcome-of-this-convoluted-dice-rolling

Comment: I don’t see *either* of those as a good reason to delete a question that already has (good, I assume from the voting) answers. There is a *reason* authors cannot delete questions that have upvoted answers.

Comment: Ah, OK. That at least explains the "why" and "how" of it. Thanks for that (and for the stats.SE link)! (I'm not going to personally offer any opinion on whether it *should've* been deleted, since I can see arguments both ways, and in any case I'm probably biased here.)